# How to get all the records from midnight until now in Postgress sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get all the records from midnight until now in Postgress sql

Comment: Is now the time you posted or the time which someone reads your post?

Comment: 'now' is the current time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
select * from your_table where date between now()::date and now();
```

> now()::date

will round current timestamp till midnight.

Comment: or `CURRENT_DATE` so you don't have to cast now()